# Sort a Column in Another Sheet Without Selecting That Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to sort columns in another sheet without selecting that sheet?
The problem is while I am running this code, I want this sheet to be hidden and I do not want it to flash over to it when I need to sort the table.  Here is my code... This works, but it does obviously select the sheet and shows you the other sheet. Maybe something with 'make active sheet' would work can you do that then say 'make active cell'.  I am not sure. Thanks guys.

```
 Application.Worksheets("RawDataLines").Select

    Application.Worksheets("RawDataLines").Range("Q5").Select
    Application.Worksheets("RawDataLines").Range("A4:R1007").Sort Key1:=Range("Q5"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:= _
        xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    Application.Worksheets("RawDataLines").Range("A5").Select
    Application.Worksheets("RawDataLines").Range("A4:R1007").Sort Key1:=Range("A5"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:= _
        xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```
Application.Worksheets("RawDataLines").Select
Application.Worksheets("RawDataLines").Range("Q5").Select
Application.Worksheets("RawDataLines").Range("A4:R1007").Sort ...
```

Could be this:

```
With Application.Worksheets("RawDataLines")
    .Range("A4:R1007").Sort  Key1:= .Range("A5")'...
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `ScreenUpdating`

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 #Your Code
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Just make sure that you set the select back to the sheet you want it on prior to setting `ScreenUpdating = True`

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem comes with the `Key1 arguments` of VBA sort method. Even though we explicitly pass range with relevant sheet, when it comes to `Key1:=Range(…)`, VBA automatically take `ActiveSheet.Range(…)`.

If We have selected some other sheet instead of the sheets of sort data, VBA shows runtime error.

To fix this problem change the code as `Key1:=Your_Sheet_With_Data.Range(Your_Range)`. For Example, above referred code can be fixed changing the code as

```
Key1:=Worksheets("RawDataLines").Range("Q5")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]! I guess you missed the fact, that this is an old question (>5Y) , not ideal for a beginner. Even you mentioned the ActiveSheet issue, your answer has less quality, than the accepted by Tim. (that most likely caused the downvote) Just delete your answer, but notice the edit made by @Slong.

Comment: VBA is "old school" and useful. Your comment got me on the right track.